# Solving Recursions Without Characteristic Polynomials

Tags: contest-math, recurrence-relations, recursion

Consider the following problem:

> Consider the sequence defined by $a_n=xa_{n-1}+ya_{n-2}$. Find the general formula for $a_n$ in terms of $a_1$ and $a_2$.

This is a pretty typical recursion. My question is: is there a way to solve this recursion without using the characteristic polynomial?

As an example, consider the following problem: (sorry for my excessive use of "consider")

> Consider the sequence defined by $a_n=xa_{n-1}+y$. Find the general formula for $a_n$ in terms of $a_1$.

A pretty elegant way of doing this is to write:

$$
a_n=xa_{n-1}+y \\
a_n+\frac{y}{x-1}=xa_{n-1}+y+\frac{y}{x-1}=xa_{n-1}+\frac{yx}{x-1} \\
\begin{align}
a_n+\frac{y}{x-1}
&=x(a_{n-1}+\frac{y}{x-1}) \\
&=x^2(a_{n-2}+\frac{y}{x-1}) \\
&=x^{n-1}(a_1+\frac{y}{x-1})
\end{align}
$$
The problem can now be easily solved from here.

Another example is the following problem:

> Consider the sequence defined by $a_n=x_na_{n-1}+y_n$ where $\{x_i\}$ and $\{y_i\}$ are also both sequences. Find the general formula for $a_n$ in terms of $a_1,x_i$ and $y_i$.

The solution can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving).

I have browsed many questions and articles on recursions, like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients) very well explained article, which unfortunately does not answer my question, and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3461091/how-do-i-solve-recurrence-relation-without-characteristic-equation). The first answer uses computer to find a pattern before proving that the pattern works, but in the context of Mathematics Olympiads, this method is clearly not viable. I could not understand the second answer, and the third answer uses generating functions. However, I am looking for an elementary and nice, elegant method of doing this, like I have shown above.

So, is there such a method? If yes, can this be generalised to recursions like $a_n=xa_{n-1}+ya_{n-2}$ or $a_n=xa_{n-1}^2+y$? Any help will be appreciated and, at my discretion, awarded with bounties.

Comment: The "pretty elegant way" you mention boils down to the transformation of an affine mapping $f(u)=xu+v$ into a linear mapping by taking the good origin, i.e., the fixed point of the affine transformation.

Comment: You may determine the *generating function* associated to the sequence.